# doctrine fetch join query on three tables

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, dql

I have three entities in my Symfony2 project:

- User
- Group
- Organisation

The fourth entity represents relation between three above:

- UserOrganisationGroup {userId, organisationId, groupId}

Now, I need fetch join query that somehow will load User and its Groups and Organisations. I though of something like:

```
SELECT u, g, o, uog 
FROM Yocto\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User u 
JOIN u.userOrganisationGroup uog
JOIN uog.organisation o
JOIN uog.group g
WHERE uog.user = 1
```

But all I get is User Entity, and Organisation and Group seems to be NULL. What am I doing wrong? I know for the fact that database has records as follows:

```
User
id | 1

Organisation
id | 1

Group
id | 1

UserOrganisationGroup
userId         |  1
groupId        |  1
organisationId |  1



array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#490 (15) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(35) "UserBundle\Entity\User"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["userOrganisationGroup"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#502 (4) {
        ["__CLASS__"]=>
        string(52) "UserBundle\Entity\UserOrganisationGroup"
        ["user"]=>
        object(stdClass)#507 (15) {
          ["__CLASS__"]=>
          string(35) "UserBundle\Entity\User"
          ["id"]=>
          int(1)
          ["userOrganisationGroup"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#525 (4) {
              ["__CLASS__"]=>
              string(52) "UserBundle\Entity\UserOrganisationGroup"
              ["user"]=>
              string(35) "UserBundle\Entity\User"
              ["group"]=>
              NULL
              ["organisation"]=>
              NULL
            }
          }
        }
        ["group"]=>
        NULL
        ["organisation"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mention or join 'uog' table at all.

```
SELECT User u,o,g
INNER JOIN u.organisation AS o
INNER JOIN u.group AS g
```

Avoid naming entities by using reserved words like Group.

Comment: Not really. User has no association named organisation. @Djuro Mandinic

Comment: Following SQL query represents what I want to achieve: SELECT 
u.username,
acl_organisations.name,
acl_groups.name AS group_name
FROM acl_users u
JOIN acl_userOrganisationGroups ON u.id = acl_userOrganisationGroups.user_id
JOIN acl_organisations ON acl_userOrganisationGroups.organisation_id = acl_organisations.id
JOIN acl_groups ON acl_userOrganisationGroups.group_id = acl_groups.id
WHERE u.id =1